# is Fetch API supported in NextJS Api Router ( NextJS Page Router Version - 13.1.6)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I'm newbie in NextJS and I'm curious about the usage of Fetch API in NextJS.

So I have an API handler where it does a fetch to a backend service:

```
  async function handler(req, res) {
    ...
    const response = await fetch('https:backend-url.com')
    ...
  }
```

I know that you can do a backend data fetch using `getServerSideProps`, which `fetch` is supported. However, I'm wondering if the `fetch` method is not supported inside an API handler router.

I'm using `fetch` in NextJS middleware, and that seems to work as well; it's supported per comment I saw in another stackoverflow article.

I'm starting to suspect `fetch` is not supported inside the API router, as I get an error in the network request when it's deployed.

```
fetch failed
```

I also get this error

```
[ERR] (node:148) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
```

Locally, it works ok but when it's deployed I get these errors.

Do I need to use `node-fetch` when using fetch in api routers?

Not sure what's going, but I want to confirm if the `fetch` method is supported in API router.

I've looked in the documentation but has no mention of api router support -> https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/supported-browsers#server-side-polyfills

Your help is appreciated, just try to learn more about NextJS

Comment: as mentioned fetch api is experimental for nodejs, it is better to use 3rd party libraries like axios, node-fetch instead. Because there is a risk of the fetch api changing later

Comment: I think you are running an old Node.js version. `fetch` is well supported by now.